# How to extract all the lines with keywords from pdf files in python?

Tags: python, parsing, txt

I have multiple txt files, from which I have to extract all the lines with the names of authors. However, sometime there are too many authors and they are written in multiple lines, or name in one line and surname in the next line. This creates me a problem, I can't extract all these lines efficiently.

```
    authors = ['Francesca Donato', 'Marisa Matias', Ignazio Corrao', and so on....]
    line_number = 0
    list_of_results = []
    # Open the file in read only mode
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as read_obj:
        # Read all lines in the file one by one
        for line in read_obj:
            line_number += 1
            # For each line, check if line contains any string from the list of strings
            for string_to_search in authors:
                if string_to_search in line:
                    list_of_results.append((line.rstrip()))
```

Comment: I can't understand; the example code doesn't appear to have anything to do with PDF files. Reading text out of a PDF realistically will require a third-party library, and is not an exact science even then. The PDF format is simply not designed for that.

Answer (score 0):

Python is fairly slow for txt parsing it is much simpler to take a list of over 700 names and compare using the operating system. In many cases python uses poppler texttopdf as its core extractor and we can run that in native OS, however your task is complicated by European names so will need compensation in each stage.

So taking one document at a time you can scan a pdf converted to text with a simple single command. (you can also use drag and drop or a folder of pdfs by first line `pdftotext -layout file(s).pdf`.

In this case only one name is repeated several times. but all you want is the count of one name found so just count it as one file one name.

```
>@for /f "tokens=1*" %a in (names.txt) do @type I201460[SD-EN].txt |find /i "%a %b"
```

```
                Circular economy: statement by Jan HUITEMA (RE, NL), rapporteur
    Reference: I-201460              Duration: 00:03:28             Location: Brussels            Date: Jan 26, 2021
  CO2 emissions. Statement by Jan HUITEMA (RE, NL), rapporteur.
                     Title: Circular economy: statement by Jan HUITEMA (RE,
                     SOUNDBITE (English), Jan HUITEMA (RE, NL),
                     SOUNDBITE (English), Jan HUITEMA (RE, NL), The main
              SOUNDBITE (English), Jan HUITEMA (RE, NL),
              SOUNDBITE (English), Jan HUITEMA (RE, NL),
00:02:16      Arrival of Jan HUITEMA (RE, NL)                                    00:00:05
```

here I have added other names in my list but to show how two can be reported as in one file save the output and reparse as required.

`@for /f "tokens=1*" %a in (names.txt) do @type EPRS_ATA(2022)729285_EN.txt |find /i "%a %b" >>result. txt`

Result.txt

```
 responsible: ENVI; Rapporteur: Simona Bonafè (S&D, Italy). For
                                         Author: Vivienne Halleux, Members' Research Service
```

To export names without context then filter the pass per input

`@for /f "tokens=1*" %a in (names.txt) do @type EPRS_ATA(2022)729285_EN.txt | @find /i "%a %b"&&echo %a %b >>result.txt`

[image]

Optionally add the filename if required inside the result.txt or use the scanned filename as result

EPRS_ATA(2022)729285_EN_Result.txt

So putting it all together as  say eurodump.bat

```
C:\poppler-22.04-09\Library\bin\pdftotext -layout -enc UTF-8 "%~1"
echo "%~1" >"%~dpn1-result.txt"
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (names.txt) do @type "%~dpn1.txt" | @find /i "%%a %%b"&&echo %%a %%b >>"%~dpn1-result.txt"
```

run that on a bunch of files or simply drag and drop one

[image]

Or use an URL to start with

`curl -O https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/PECH-AM-691333_EN.pdf`

[image]